# why this code gives Unhandled exception failure

Tags: c++

I used a vector because I don't know the number of inputs, but it doesn't work. What should i do?

```
vector <string> str;

str[0] = "entity1 ABCDE 2x2 infected";

std::istringstream ss(str[0]);

std::string token;

vector<string> genes;

while (std::getline(ss, token, ' ')) {
    genes.push_back(token);
}
for (int i = 0; i < genes.size(); i++) {
    cout << genes[i];
}
```

Comment: Why is `str` a `vector<string>` instead of a single `string`? And since the vector is empty, indexing into it is undefined.

Comment: `str[0] = "entity1 ABCDE 2x2 infected";` is a bug because the str is an empty vector.

Comment: `vector <string> str = {"entity1 ABCDE 2x2 infected"};` -- That will add an item to the vector.  As to the rest of your code, see earlier comments.

Comment: If your idea is to put many strings in a vector one after another, in order to form bigger string, it is wrong!

Comment: I want to put many strings in a vector and i dont know their number. thats because i create a vector. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
vector <string> str;
str[0] = "entity1 ABCDE 2x2 infected";
```

`str` is empty, so you have undefined behavior when you access the first element (at index `0`). You could fix this by allocating space for one string in the vector:

```
vector <string> str(1);
```

or by directly creating a vector with one string (which will create the string, and place it into the vector correctly):

```
vector <string> str = {"entity1 ABCDE 2x2 infected"};
```

However, from your example code, it seems you don't need a `vector` here at all, and a single `string` would suffice:

```
string str = "entity1 ABCDE 2x2 infected";
std::istringstream ss(str);
```

Comment: N.B. it's just not allocating space; it's creating a `string`. A perhaps subtle, but certainly important, distinction.

Comment: I don't think that "assigning" (initialising) example will compile though

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings edited wording slightly. And fixed the typo, thanks for pointing it out.